# XSLT not reading tag html tag <p>

Tags: html, xml, xslt

This is my XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
    indent="yes" />
<xsl:output doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
    doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd" />


<xsl:template match="/">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pt">
        <head>
            <title>João Cona</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="T01Catalogue.css"
                charset="UTF-8" />
        </head>
        <body>


            <xsl:apply-templates select="//utilizadores" />

        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="utilizadores">
        <xsl:call-template name="username">
            <xsl:with-param name="id" select="//utilizador/@username"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="birthdate">
            <xsl:with-param name="id" select="//utilizador/@username"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="username">
    <xsl:param name="id"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="name">
        <xsl:with-param name="nome">
            <xsl:value-of select="//utilizador[@username = $id]/nome"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="birthdate">
    <xsl:param name="id"/>
    <xsl:call-template name="dataNasc">
        <xsl:with-param name="data">
            <xsl:value-of select="//utilizador[@username = $id]/birthday"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="name">
    <xsl:param name="nome"/>
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="$nome"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="dataNasc">
    <xsl:param name="data"/>
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="$data"/>
    </p>
</xsl:template>
```

I have this output (on HTML):

```
Guilherme Luís1996-11-28
```

I was expecting this (on HTML):

```
Guilherme Luís
1996-11-28
```

In the snippet you can find my XML code, if that helps.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="1.xsl"?>

<xml_tube>
 <utilizadores>
  <utilizador username="Guicky" password="futurama96">
   <nome>Guilherme Luís</nome>
   <birthday>1996-11-28</birthday>
   <foto href="guilhas.jpg"/>
  </utilizador>
  <utilizador username="Daisy" password="woofwoof11">
   <nome>Daisy Luís</nome>
   <birthday>2011-04-04</birthday>
   <foto href="daisy.png"/>
  </utilizador>
  <utilizador username="Anabela65" password="crumble65">
   <nome>Anabela Ribeiro</nome>
   <birthday>1965-04-02</birthday>
   <foto href="belinha.jpg"/>
  </utilizador>
  <utilizador username="Izzie" password="lagartixa">
   <nome>Isadora Luís</nome>
   <birthday>1988-06-27</birthday>
   <foto href="izzie.jpg"/>
  </utilizador>
 </utilizadores>
 <videos_pub>
  <video id="Vid1" publisher="Daisy" duracao="3:37" data="2016-02-29">
   <título>Who let the dogs out? - Baha Men</título>
   <thumb>http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/Qkuu0Lwb5EM/hqdefault.jpg</thumb>
   <descrição>My favorite song, lol.</descrição>
   <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qkuu0Lwb5EM</hyperlink>
   <qualidade pixelization="1080p"/>
   <qualidade pixelization="480p"/>
   <likes liked="Guicky"/>
   <related></related>
  </video>
  <video id="Vid2" publisher="Guicky" duracao="4:01" data="2016-02-29">
   <título>Desiigner - Timmy Turner</título>
   <thumb>http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/JzmRt2VgKYQ/hqdefault.jpg</thumb>
   <descrição>Timmy Timmy Timmy Turner.</descrição>
   <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/embed/ProbPpO_8oo</hyperlink>
   <qualidade pixelization="720p"/>
   <qualidade pixelization="1080p"/>
   <likes liked="Anabela65"/>
   <likes liked="Daisy"/>
   <related></related>
  </video>
  <video id="Vid3" publisher="Guicky" duracao="3:47" data="2016-02-29">
   <título>I'm all the way up - Fat Joe</título>
   <thumb>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y2ak_oBeC-I</thumb>
   <descrição>Nothing can stop me, I'm all the way up.</descrição>
   <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/embed/y2ak_oBeC-I</hyperlink>
   <qualidade pixelization="480p"/>
   <qualidade pixelization="720p"/>
   <related></related>
  </video>
  <video id="Vid4" publisher="Anabela65" duracao="3:21" data="2016-02-29">
   <título>Putzgrilla - Sentadinha</título>
   <thumb>http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/QC4JbIvIhdI/hqdefault.jpg</thumb>
   <descrição>Dá uma sentadinha.</descrição>
   <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QC4JbIvIhdI</hyperlink>
   <qualidade pixelization="720p"/>
   <likes liked="Guicky"/>
   <likes liked="Daisy"/>
   <related></related>
  </video>
  <video data="2017-01-13" duracao="02:16" id="Vid5" publisher="Izzie">
   <título>Yann Tiersen - La Valse d'Amelie</título>
   <thumb>http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/uzurqBnALkw/hqdefault.jpg</thumb>
   <descrição>A minha música preferida.</descrição>
   <hyperlink>https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzurqBnALkw</hyperlink>
   <qualidade pixelization="720p"/>
   <likes liked="Guicky"/>
   <likes liked="Anabela65"/>
   <related></related>
  </video>
 </videos_pub>
 <playlist>
  <lista owner="Guicky" dataIns="2016-10-24" id="PV1">
   <titulo>BEST MUSIC.</titulo>
   <descricao>Compilation of my favourite music videos.</descricao>
   <gostosL gostouL="Guicky"/>
   <links_vid vid="Vid2"/>
   <links_vid vid="Vid3"/>
   <administradores>
    <admin ref="Guicky"/>
    <admin ref="Daisy"/>
   </administradores>
   <editores>
    <editor ref="Guicky"/>
   </editores>
   <subscritores>
    <subs ref="Daisy"/>
    <subs ref="Anabela65"/>
   </subscritores>
   <thumbnail link="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/QC4JbIvIhdI/hqdefault.jpg"/>
  </lista>
  <lista owner="Anabela65" dataIns="2016-02-29" id="PV2">
   <titulo>Sentadinha!</titulo>
   <descricao>Siting lesson's with Guicky's mom!</descricao>
   <links_vid vid="Vid4"/>
   <administradores>
    <admin ref="Anabela65"/>
    <admin ref="Guicky"/>
   </administradores>
   <editores>
    <editor ref="Anabela65"/>
   </editores>
   <subscritores>
    <subs ref="Guicky"/>
    <subs ref="Daisy"/>
   </subscritores>
   <thumbnail link="http://i3.ytimg.com/vi/uMK0prafzw0/hqdefault.jpg"/>
  </lista>
 </playlist>
 <comentarios>
  <comentario id="C1" refV="Vid1" user="Guicky" data="2016-10-23">
   <text>AHAHAHAHA, bom vídeo.</text>
   <gosto gostou="Daisy"/>
   <respostas>
    <texto autor="Daisy">Grande clássico!</texto>
   </respostas>
  </comentario>
  <comentario id="C2" refL="Vid2" user="Anabela65" data="2016-10-22">
   <text>Timmy timmy timmy turner...</text>
   <gosto gostou="Guicky"/>
   <gosto gostou="Daisy"/>
   <respostas>
    <texto autor="Guicky">U know it.</texto>
    <resposta autor="Daisy">LOL!</resposta>
   </respostas>
  </comentario>
 </comentarios>
</xml_tube>
```

Any idea why this isn't working? Why is the XSLT not reading the

tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` to the root of the stylesheet element (i.e. `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">`) so that all result elements are XHTML elements and not only those in the template where you currently have the namespace declaration.